# How to add product to compare products using product id programmatically in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, compare

How to **add product** to **compare products** using **product id**  **programmatically**.

Please give me suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Compare\Item` to add compared products. (We should inject this class to the constructor or can use a Dirty Playground)

Take a look the table `catalog_compare_item` in database. We need to add the customer id to the product compare item. AND, you also need to add the data to `report_compared_product_index` table - `\Magento\Reports\Model\Product\Index\ComparedFactory`.

```
    /** @var $compareItem \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Compare\Item */

    /** @var $compareFactory \Magento\Reports\Model\Product\Index\ComparedFactory */

    $productIds = [1,2, 4, 5]; // For example data.
    $customerId = 1; // For example data. Make sure the customer exists.
     foreach ($productIds as $productId) {
        $compareItem->setCustomerId($customerId);
        $compareItem->addProductData($productId);
        $compareItem->save();
        $compareItem->unsetData();

        $viewData = [
            'product_id' => $productId,
            'customer_id' => $customerId
        ];
        $compareFactory->create()->setData($viewData)->save();
    }
```

Comment: why this line: $compareItem->unsetData(); exists?

Answer (score 0):

1. Inject the following class in the **constructor** where you want to use it.

> \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Compare\ListCompare

```
public function __construct(
....
....
\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Compare\ListCompare $listCompare,
....
) {
...
$this->listCompare = $listCompare;
...
}
```

2) use **addProducts** method of this class to add products to compare list.

```
$productIds = <your product Ids>;
$this->listCompare->addProducts($productIds);
```